# Import existing local repo into eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, bitbucket

What is missing?.. imported Git local repo into workspace, but in the workspace it's not marked with J as usual in Eclipse , but instead with the repo icon, and is not runnable, i cant run the project. can't seem to figure out what is missing? ...no solution ofc .. after googling like creazy.

successfully cloned repository from bitbucket,
right click and imported local repository into workspace, when i right click on it and go to team.. every usual git options and stuff are available, but the project is not runnable. What is missing?

Comment: Are you getting an error? What do you mean by "not runnable", do you get a "no main class found" or something? Do you have the name of the repo in squared brackets next to the project name in the workspace?

Comment: Solved. Sorry, i just, had to restart eclipse, as simple as that,  ... that's almost embarrassing! and annoying .. thanks anyway!

Comment: liked your name :D ^^